# "Missing operating system" error on boot

Tags: fedora, boot, boot-loader

I replaced Windows 8 with Linux Mint. After the installation had completed, I restarted only to face a black screen with `missing operating system`.

I thought the problem was with Mint so I decided to try Fedora. Again I got the same problem. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: During the install process are you wiping the drive clean, including removing existing partitions created by Windows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is usually caused by a stupid bios that checks the partition table for the MS-DOS boot flag, and if no partition has it, prints this message and refuses to boot.  Run `sudo fdisk /dev/sda` and print the partition table with `p`.  If no partition has the boot flag, then set it with the `a` command, and finally save and exit with `w`.

Comment: Can't argue with that.  And this procedure has saved me periodically.  Though I eventually just flagged the first partition of almost all drives as "bootable" (possibly to my own detriment).

Comment: After I toggled the "legacy boot flag" the filesystem is not longer visible to me for mounting. Should it be that way?

Comment: @PetaspeedBeaver, definitely not.  The partition flags are ignored by Linux ( well, apparently these days Redhat is using them for silly things ).  The only thing the boot flag does is tell the DOS/Windows MBR which partition to boot, which doesn't matter if you aren't booting directly to DOS/Windows, unless you have a silly bios that gives this complaint if no partition has the flag.